# Android Gradle multiple flavor dimensions and different sourceSets

Tags: android, gradle

I have multiple flavor dimensions and depending on combination chosen there should be different library assembled inside APK. Is it possible to make this generic so that I don't have to create sections inside sourceSets for every flavor combination (like devLocalDebug is one of those sections)? In other words I would like to get build type & flavors of current Gradle build.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        // How to get current flavors used?
        // jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../cmd_build/cmake_output/<build type + combination of flavor dimensions>']
    }
    devLocalDebug {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../cmd_build/cmake_output/deb_dev_local']
    }
    atestLocalDebug {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../cmd_build/cmake_output/deb_atest_local']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get flavor by using very similar code as this one: https://github.com/NerdWallet/react-native-config/blob/7825fc4f2c11b97178d746583ca0a67c20b5c8ff/android/dotenv.gradle#L4